# Store data with up to 800 lines of code as strings or files?

Tags: database, string, mongodb, performance, file

I´m currently developing a scanning software, where the user can upload his code (with up too about 500-800 lines of code - sometimes only 20 lines of code) for a scan.
I´m storing the content in my db and am wondering, if it´s mroe efficient to store potentially “huge” files as a string or file in my database.
I couldn´t really find a specific case for my question, because it´s really flexible and so on.

So yeah, there can and will be those files with hundreds of lines of code. What would you say is the more efficient way to store those?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What matters to you more? Speed or Memory? It would take more time for a program to access a file than a string in memory. However, if you don't have a lot of memory, you'll need to use files.

Comment: I see, so time is money in that case basically?

Comment: Yes. Time is very important if you're dealing with many clients at the same time.